# TLS and clientAuthRequired of operation security for fabric

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have two questions about operation security of fabric.

1.In the official documentation( https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_service.html?highlight=security#operations-security ), it says:"When TLS is enabled, a valid client certificate must be provided in order to access all resources unless explicitly noted otherwise below." Does this mean that when I access the operation RESTFUL API(e.g.GET /logspec) by curl or POSTMAN, I need to provide client certificate, right? If so, the client certificate must be generated by the corresponding organization's Fabric CA, right?

2.The documentation also says:"When clientAuthRequired is also enabled, the TLS layer will require a valid client certificate regardless of the resource being accessed.". I can't figure out what is the difference between "TLS" and "clientAuthRequired" configuration. Could any expert tell me this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes ... it means that when TLS is enabled you will require a client certificate (expect where noted refers to the fact that the `/healthz` endpoint does not require a client certificate).  The client certificate must be issued by a CA configured using the `operations.tls.clientRootCAs.files` property for the peer and/or the `Operations.TLS.RootCAs` property for the orderer.
2. If `clientAuthRequired` is enabled, then all endpoints will require a client certificate (again for now this means that `/healthz` would require a client cert).